# Import address book contacts, store in array and save to database

Tags: php, jquery, database, arrays, contacts

Im using [Contact Grabber API](http://stescodes.com/contactgrabber_apidoc.aspx) to retrieve address book contacts.

My intention is to then allow the user to select their contacts (via checkbox list) and insert these values into a database.

HTML for list:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_email" value="{users_email}" />
```

JQUERY to post data to PHP form

```
    $("#divDone").click(function() {
        var data = { 'user_email' : []};
        $(":checked").each(function() {
          data['user_email'].push($(this).val());
        });
        $.post("ajax.php", data);
    });
```

ajax.php

```
var_export($_POST);
```

The ajax.php file echo's the following sample (of selecting two contacts)

```
array (
 'user_email' => 
  array (
    0 => 'gmail',
    1 => '{email1}',
    2 => '{email2}',
  ),
)
```

How do extract the email values and store them into my database? Is this method correct?

Thank you all in advance

George

Comment: So everything works and you want someone to say Yes right?

Comment: @PezCuckow no... I need to extract the emails values in the array and store them into the database... which is what I am unable to do. Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know what a MySQL database is and how to set up a table, see below for a basic example where you take all the emails and just put them in a table called `Emails` which has one column `email`

```
//Did we get a post?
if(empty($_POST['user_email']) && is_array($_POST['user_email'])) {
  echo "No Email's received. Check the post.";
} else {
  $emails = $_POST['user_email'];

  $errors = "";

  //## Connect to MYSQL here ##//
  $con = null; //SEE ABOVE

  //For all the posted emails
  foreach($emails as $email) {
    //Trim and escape the input
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($email));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Emails (email) ";
    $sql += "VALUES ('$email')";

    //If an error occurred add it to the list
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) $errors += mysql_error()."\n";
  } //for each

  //Any errors?
  if(!empty($errors)) echo $errors;
}
```